# Python inspect.getcomments(module) doesn't return the first comment if it's a shebang

Tags: python, inspect

When a Python file contains a shebang (`#!blabla`), the function `getcomments` from the module `inspect` doesn't return it.
What can I do to get the shebang from a module object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang is only valid if it is the first line of the file ... So, it seems like you could do something like:

```
import module
fname = module.__file__
with open(fname) as fin:
    shebang = next(fin)
```

Of course, I've jumped over a bunch of subtleties ... (making sure the first line is actually a comment, making sure that we've grabbed a `.py` file instead of a `.pyc` file, etc.).  Those checks and substitutions should be easy enough to make though if you want to make it more robust.

And, I suppose an alternative to using `__file__` magic would be to use `inspect.getsourcelines`:

```
 shebang = inspect.getsourcelines(module)[0]
 if not shebang.startswith('#!'):
    pass #Not a shebang :)
```